# "error: input is self closing and should not have content" with nonexistent tag?

Tags: html, pug

I get a `input is self closing and should not have content.` error, but as you can see below there is no input tag to have any content. I've even deleted the line the error references and it still happens. I'm using jade.

```
    26|         li(class=(view==="redeem" ?  "active": ""))
    27|           a(href="/transfer/redeem#action") Redeem Code
  > 28|       hr(id='action',class='mobile',style='padding-top: 50px;')
    29|       h2#track-balance(style="text-align: left") Balance: 
    30|             span.currency #{balace}
    31|       br
    32|      - if (success === false) {   
    33|            div.alert.alert-danger
    34|              strong Sorry!
    35|              | Your request could not be completed.
    36|        - } else if (success === true) {   
    37|             div.alert.alert-success
    38|               strong Success!
    39|               | Your request completed!
    40|        - }
```

Per comment below
The actual error is in another included file:

```
|28       input(id='friend_fbid',type='hidden',name='say[facebook_id]')
```

There's nothing inside this input though, not even any trailing whitespace.

Comment: Can you show a few more lines, preferably the entire div/section? I've received errors from jade that aren't actually on the line mentioned.

Comment: There's no input in this file there are some `include`s down lower though.

Comment: So somehow the debugger is outputting those as the lines where the error is located but the file and line referece is actually to another file which is included.

Answer (score 0):

hr tag doesn't have those properties, so it's throwing an error saying it's self closing, as it's literally just `<hr>` when rendered. So it's self closing and hence takes no actions/properties, content as jade calls it. Like `<br />` tags but without the closing slash.

If you wish to assign those properties either make a custom Hr by using a span and a line in css.

Or if it's just the padding then add a div with padding top 50px.

Comment: This is why I don't like html.

Comment: Nope, removed all the attributes and it still gives the same error. I also don't understand why it's saying the error has to do with an input tag. Also, Mozilla says that those are global attributes and `hr` elements include them: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hr#Attributes

Comment: Hi, admittedly it does, but they're mostly deprecated in HTML5.  Just seen your updates/comments, are the facebook_id and friend_fbid variables?  I.e dynamic